# using C# language to create for iOS and Android

Tags: c#, android, ios

I'm creating my app using Objective C and Xcode 6.1 for iOS app. However, if I want to port my app to Android I'd need to now recreate the code in Java. For next app to avoid recreating the entire app in Java, can I just use C# (sharp) Language for both iOS and Android without having to use Objective C/Swift/Java? My friend said I can, but how?

Comment: Is xamarin studio for iOS and Android is  like Xcode for iOS? It's just a platform used? Can I use the xamarin studio to simultaneously work on iOS and Android? Or for example do i first use xamarin studio with C# language to create for iOS and then copy and paste the C# code and start working on Android with xamarin studio?

Comment: yes..you can develop apps for both platforms with one project.

Comment: So I just copy and paste the code? And for iOS storyboard or whatever xamarin calls it, I just copy and paste to Android?

Answer (score 0):

> can I just use C# (sharp) Language for both iOS and Android

Yes you can use [XAMARIN](https://xamarin.com/) and [Mono](http://www.monodevelop.com/)

Comment: The app store doesn't mind that I'm not using Xcode to build an app for Apple?

Comment: I have no idea releasing an App to Store but I believe Apple and Google wont mind if your write code in different language.

Comment: The point of writing code for iOS device is to release it in App store. Otherwise, what's the use? So with C# I can use Xamarin Visual Studio for iOS and Android. If I create the code for app on iOS and I can just copy and paste the iOS copy onto the Android Visual Studio app?

Answer (score 0):

There are two way. You can write app for iOS or android with Csharp using Xamarin.Android or Xamarin.ios. With these tools you have to know how apps are written in Java or Objective C because the UI have to be written using same way (activity....) but in csharp.

Otherwise you can use Xamarin.forms, a library that help you to write in csharp cross platforms app. So you have a PCL project where you write the great part of your app, and iOS and android project used for very little piece of code (startup app, custom renderers...)